# Ruby - Making test pass

Tags: ruby, tdd

I'm trying to make this test pass and am not sure how to go about making this pass.

**TEST**

```
def test_it_is_thirsty_by_default
  vampire = Vampire.new("Count von Count")
  assert vampire.thirsty?
end

def test_it_is_not_thirsty_after_drinking
  vampire = Vampire.new("Elizabeth Bathory")
  vampire.drink
  refute vampire.thirsty?
end
```

**CODE**

```
def thirsty?
  true
end

def drink
  thirsty? === false
end
```

It is giving a failure message on the last test:

`Failed refutation, no message given`

What am I missing? My thought is that initially, the vampire is thirsty(true) and then defined a method that would then make the vampire not thirsty(false).

**EDIT**

Even if I reassign the drink method to:

`thirsty? = false`

I get a syntax error pointing to the `=` sign.

Comment: You haven't defined the class `Vampire`, for which `thirsty?` and `drink` are presumably instance methods. The class also needs an `initialize` method. Why `===` rather than `==` in `drink`?

Comment: oh i didn't include the rest of the code, but I did define a class `Vampire` and an `initialize` method that has `instance variables` of `name` and `pet`

Comment: It's just a personal preference to use `===` over `==`

Comment: Your example code should be complete enough for readers to run it and/or modified code without having to guess how gaps are to be filled in. I suggest you edit. Incidentally, I just happened to see your comments that reply to my earlier comment. For me to be notified by SO you need to include @username.

Comment: "It's just a personal preference to use `===` over `==`" – Huh? The two mean completely different things, the question of "preference" doesn't even apply.

Comment: @JörgWMittag i just read up on ruby equality operators and it seems that it's different from javascript. Is `===` only used in case statements?

Comment: @mph85 `===` is the method called by [`case`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression), hence "case equality". You rarely call it explicitly.

Comment: @Stefan case would the ruby equivalent to Javascript's switch statements?

Comment: @mph85 yes, with a few differences.

Comment: @Stefan so you're saying that in Javascript you can do things like compare if `1 === '1' (false)`, but you can't do `1 === '1'` in ruby unless this was in a case statement?

Comment: @mph85 no no no. JavaScript's `===` and Ruby's implementations for `===` are very different. In Ruby each class can implement its own `===` to provide meaningful behavior when used as a "pattern" in a `case` expression. For example, [`Range#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) returns `true` if the argument is an element of the range. This allows you to write `case 1` and match it via `when 0..2`. Internally, `(0..2) === 1` is called, which returns `true`.

Comment: @Stefan so in my example above, I was questioned about my use of `===`, what's wrong there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194415/discussion-between-stefan-and-mph85).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a couple things, most importantly some kind of writer method that allows you to store that fact that `@thirsty` is getting updated inside of your `drink` method call

There's a couple different ways to do this but I've shown one below with a few notes:

```
require 'test/unit'

class Vampire
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @thirsty = true # true by default
  end

  def drink
    @thirsty = false # updates @thirsty for the respective instance
  end

  def thirsty?
    @thirsty
  end
end

class VampireTests < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_it_is_thirsty_by_default
    vampire = Vampire.new("Count von Count")
    assert vampire.thirsty?
  end

  def test_it_is_not_thirsty_after_drinking
    vampire = Vampire.new("Elizabeth Bathory")
    vampire.drink
    refute vampire.thirsty?
  end
end
```

Comment: hm i tried the `alias_method` and it gave me `alias_method: undefined method `thirsty' for class `Vampire' (NameError)`

Comment: how would i solve this if i just keep the `def thirsty?` method

Comment: @mph85 it should probably be `attr_reader :name, :thirsty`. But you can also implement it as a stand-alone method yourself: `def thirsty? ; @thirsty ; end` (semicolon = newline). It merely returns the value of `@thirsty`, i.e. either `true` or `false`.

Comment: @Stefan is correct, I copy/pasted a typo. If you update the reader as noted, it should work. I updated my answer to add it as a reader

Comment: I edited this to remove the attr_reader/alias based on feedback from a follow up question. It wasn't necessary and looking back on it I don't even know why I had the alias and the attr_reader to begin with.