# When should I use an Alias Method? - Ruby

Tags: ruby, alias-method

I've looked through and haven't seen an answer to:

What would you use an alias method?

```
class Vampire
 attr_reader :name, :thirsty

 alias_method :thirsty?, :thirsty
end
```

Is the only reason I would use one is to be able to use a question mark with whatever method I define? I believe you can't use question marks with instance variables.

Comment: It's a method that makes aliases of methods: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Module.html#method-i-alias_method.

Comment: so if i wanted to make an instance variable called `thirsty?`, I wouldn't be able to because of the `?`, so I would use an alias_method to make a new copy of `thirsty` and changed it to `thirsty?`. That makes sense?

Comment: I understand the question and no, it does not make sense in ruby. Why create a method only to rename it? Create it with the right name from the start. `def thirsty? @thirsty; end`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev take a look at this example someone gave me for my other question, you're saying that, that stuff is extraneous? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56420576/ruby-making-test-pass?noredirect=1#comment99472049_56420576

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I posted the answer on the other post, and added my reasoning as an answer on this post. tldr; the code snippet was short, i threw something out there that met the requirement of passing the spec but I didn't go back and think about it in too much depth (the attr_reader & alias weren't really necessary)

Comment: @JayDorsey: ah, I see, thanks.

Comment: I would not expect you to see answers here to the question you pose, as I think most members would regard the question as "off topic" because it is "too broad" for SO. See [this faq](https://stackoverflow.com/help). I suggest you google for articles on the subject (e.g., "Ruby alias uses"). One that will come up is [this one](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/11/ruby-alias-keyword/). Note that aliases can be created with the keyword `alias` or the method `alias_method`. All articles on either will no doubt cover the other as well, and explain the differences.

Comment: @mph85 did you see the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56420576/ruby-making-test-pass?noredirect=1#comment99444846_56420912) I posted under Jay Dorsey's answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is from an earlier question I responded to, where I proposed using `alias_method`, so I have a little bit of extra context into this to explain it's use in that context.

In your code snippet, you have a bit of code that reads `attr_reader :thirsty` that is basically a getter for an instance variable of the same name (`@thirsty`)

```
def thirsty
  @thirsty
end
```

In the original code snippet, you had an assertion that was:

```
refute vampire.thirsty?
```

You also had code that simply returned `true` for `thirsty?` method, which failed your assertion.

There are at least two ways you could have modified your code so that the call to `thirsty?` worked and your assertion passed:

Create a method that calls the `thirsty` reader, or access the `@thirsty` instance variable itself:

```
def thirsty?
  thirsty # or @thirsty
end
```

The other way is to use `alias_method`, which is functionally equivalent to the above. It aliases `thirsty?` to `thirsty` which is an `attr_reader` which reads from the `@thirsty` instance variable

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56420912/2892779) to the other answer I gave

You might be better off not using an attr_reader at all, instead just doing as Sergio noted in his comment:

```
class Vampire
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @thirsty = true
  end

  def thirsty?
    @thirsty
  end

  def drink
    @thirsty = false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two reasons why one would use [`Module#alias_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-alias_method), one is current and valid, and the other is obsolete and was never actually necessary anyway.

The first reason is that you simply want to have two methods with different names that do the exact same thing. One reason for that could be that there are two equally widely-used terms for the same action, and you want to make it easier for people write code that is understandable to their community. (Some examples in the Ruby core library are the collection methods, which have names that are familiar to people coming from functional programming languages, such as `map`, `reduce`, people coming the Smalltalk family of programming languages, such as `collect`, `inject`, `select`, and standard English names, such as `find_all`.) Another possibility would be that you build a *Fluent Interface* and want it to read more fluently, like this:

```
play this
and that
and something_else
```

In this case, `and` could be an alias for `play`.

Another, related reason (let's call it reason 1.5) is that you want to implement some protocol and you already have a method that implements that protocol's semantics correctly, but it has the wrong name. Let's assume a hypothetical collections framework which has two methods `map_seq` and `map_nonseq`. The first one performs a `map` and guarantees the order of side-effects, whereas the second one does not guarantee the order of side-effects and may even perform the mapping operation asynchronously, concurrently, or in parallel. These two methods have actually different semantics, but if your data structure does not lend itself to parallelization, then you can simply implement `map_seq` and make `map_nonseq` an alias.

In this case, the driver is not so much that you want to provide two names for the same operation, but rather that you want to provide the same implementation for two names (if that sentence makes sense :-D ).

The second major reason why `alias_method` was used in the past, has to do with an important detail of its semantics: when you override or monkey-patch either of the two methods, this will only affect *that* name, but not the other. This was used in the past for *wrapping* the behavior of a method, like this:

```
class SomeClass
  def some_method
    "Hello World"
  end
end
```

This is a little boring. We want our method to SHOUT! But, we don't want to just copy and re-implement the method, we want to re-use its internal implementation without having to know how it is implemented internally. And we want to monkey-patch it, so that all clients of this method have the shouting behavior. The popular way to do this was something like this:

```
class SomeClass
  alias_method :__some_method_without_shouting :some_method

  def __some_method_with_shouting
    __some_method_without_shouting.upcase
  end

  alias_method :some_method :__some_method_with_shouting
end
```

In this example, we use `alias_method` to create a "backup" of the method we are monkey-patching, so that we can call it from within our monkey-patched version of the method. (Otherwise, the method would be gone.) This is actually the use case given in the documentation of `alias_method`.

This idiom was so popular and widely-used that some libraries even provided an implementation for it, e.g. ActiveSupport's [`Module#alias_method_chain`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/Module.html#method-i-alias_method_chain).

Note, however that this idiom has some not-so-nice properties. One is that we are polluting the namespace with all those `_with_` and `_without_` methods. E.g. when you look at an object's methods, you will see all of those. The other problem is that people can still call the old method directly, but presumably we had a reason to patch it, because we don't *want* the old behavior. (Otherwise, we could have just made a method with a new name that calls the old one, e.g. `shout`.)

There has always been a better alternative that was not so widely-used:

```
class SomeClass
  some_method_without_shouting = instance_method(:some_method)

  define_method(:some_method) do
    some_method_without_shouting.bind(self).().upcase
  end
end
```

Here, we store the old method in a local variable and we use a block to define the new method (via [`Module#define_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-define_method)). The local variable goes out of scope at the end of the class body, so it can never be accessed anywhere ever again. But blocks are *closures*, they close over their surrounding lexical environment, and thus the block passed to `define_method` (and *only* this block) still has access to the variable binding. That way, the old implementation is completely hidden and there is no namespace pollution.

However, as of Ruby 2.0, there is a much better solution for this method wrapping: [`Module#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-prepend). The beauty of `prepend` is that it is "just inheritance", and we can simply use `super`:

```
module Shouter
  def some_method
    super.upcase
  end
end

class SomeClass
  prepend Shouter
end
```

`Module#prepend` is the reason why `Module#alias_method_chain` was deprecated in ActiveSupport 5.0 and removed in 5.1, for example. All these contortions are simply no longer necessary.

So, to summarize: there were two main reasons why `alias_method` was used: literally making an alias, i.e. two names for the same operation, and creating a backup copy for method wrapping. The second is no longer valid and maybe arguably never was. Today, only the first reason is a valid reason to use `alias_method`.