# Difference between alias foo bar and just foo = bar

Tags: ruby

While learning ruby with tutorial on rubylearning i got to 'using alias' part of it.
I cant understand what is the difference between using alias like in example:

```
def oldmtd  
  "old method"  
end  
alias newmtd oldmtd  
def oldmtd  
  "old improved method"  
end  
puts oldmtd  
puts newmtd
```

with output

```
old improved method
old method
```

and just assigning a new variable to this function, like:

```
def oldmtd  
  "old method"  
end  
newmtd = oldmtd  
def oldmtd  
  "old improved method"  
end  
puts oldmtd  
puts newmtd
```

with the same output:

```
old improved method
old method
```

Please, tell me what is actual difference and when it is correct to use 'alias'?

Comment: Add a required argument to the method and you'll notice the difference. eg. `def oldmtd(value); "old method with value: #{value}"; end` (replace the semicolons with newline characters).

Comment: Also note that your example doesn't work at all if you do it inside a class with instance methods. They only appear equivalent in this case because you're using global functions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `newmtd = oldmtd` you are not assigning a new variable to a function; you are assigning a variable to the *result* of a function, that is, a string. In Python terms: `newmtd = oldmtd()`

Answer (score 1):

Alias allows you to call an object with a different name. When you do variable assignment, you will assign it the value of whatever is returned by the right side of the `=` operator.

When you redefine the original method, you also redefine the aliased method because it still calls the original method for which it has been aliased.

However if you are aliasing a method, you probably want to use `alias_method` instead.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763121/should-i-use-alias-or-alias-method) for more on this.

As for when or why to use alias, see [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56511244/when-should-i-use-an-alias-method-ruby).

Comment: `alias` and `alias_method` have different use-cases. You want to use `alias` to statically alias methods and `alias_method` to dynamically alias methods. An advantage of `alias` is that it's picked up by RDoc, while `alias_method` isn't. Check out the Ruby style guide. https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#alias-method-lexically

Comment: pretty sure RDoc can handle non-variable `alias_method` calls